# Pointers in array of Structures in C

Tags: c

What i intend to achieve with this code is to take a string character from main function, and then assign it to name in structure at a specific index.
Example: It should print for me `Name=> Charles Key=> 0`
Next line will be `Name=> George Key=> 1`...and so on. But it rather picks the last name entered and use it for all though my structure is an array of structure. I don't also want to take it direct in the main...like `scanf("%s", &node[i].name)` because in the real project i am building, i will calculate for i based on the what the user enters. Please help me out. Thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
typedef struct{
   int key;
   char *name;
}test;

int main(){
test node[5];

int i;
char see[10];
 //for loop for taking string character in see and then assigning name in structure to it 
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
 printf("Enter name\t");
 scanf("%s", &see);
 //assigns name in structure index i to see
 node[i].name=see;
 node[i].key=i;
}
//prints data stored in structure
for(i=0; i<5; i++){
  printf("Name=> %s\t\tKey=> %d",node[i].name, node[i].key);
}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to malloc space inside the struct and copy the text rather than assigning it. When you assign the pointer you are effectively making the struct's pointer point to the same memory so the next time you read into that memory you overwrite the old value.

Try replacing:

```
node[i].name = see;
```

with:

```
node[i].name = malloc(strlen(see) + 1);
if (node[i].name == NULL)
{
   // Handle Malloc error
}
strncpy(node[i].name, see, strlen(see) + 1);
```

Comment: ohkk...i new it was overwriting the previous characters but i didn't know i needed to create space for it. Thanks a lot twain

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oh nice both methods are working. thanks too

Comment: @BLUEPIXY oops typo on my part missed the +1. Personally I prefer `strncpy` to `strcpy` since it's easier to make it safe but in this instance it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

Change as per following...

1. `char *name;`           ----> `char name[10];`
2. `scanf("%s", &see);` ----> `scanf("%s", see);`
3. `node[i].name=see;`  ----> `strcpy(node[i].name, see);`